# Angular 2 Declaration of public instance member variable not allowed

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm

Here is a link to an image of the error I am getting:
https://snag.gy/JnDOq1.jpg

Here is a link to an image of the code that is causing the error:
https://snag.gy/XtBU6y.jpg

I have in my component an array of json objects that I loop through in my component. It works fine in localhost but when I try to build for production I get this error:

```
[12:46:56] Starting 'build.prod'...
[12:46:56] Starting 'clean.prod'...
[12:46:56] Deleted dist/prod
[12:46:56] Deleted dist/tmp
[12:46:56] Finished 'clean.prod' after 5.82 ms
[12:46:56] Starting 'tslint'...
app/home/home.component.ts[34, 5]: Declaration of public instance member     variable not allowed to appear after declaration of public instance member function
app/home/home.component.ts[17, 17]: block is empty
app/home/home.component.ts[21, 1]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[34, 13]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[44, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[52, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[60, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[68, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[76, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[84, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[92, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[100, 15]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[108, 16]: trailing whitespace
app/home/home.component.ts[116, 16]: trailing whitespace
etc
```

What the _apps array looks like:

```
_apps = 
[{
myId: 1,
title: 'title',
url: 'https://google.com/',
name: 'name',
description: 'desc',
state: 'Demo'
},
{
myId: 2, 
title: 'title',
url: 'https://google.com/',
name: 'name',
description: 'desc',
state: 'Live'
},
{
myId: 3, 
title: 'title',
url: 'https://google.com/',
name: 'name',
description: 'desc',
state: 'Live'
},
etc
```

I am unsure what the trailing whitespace is as there is no space as far as I am aware?

Comment: Please add the code to your post so we can actually look into it and try it.

Comment: But to give a hint: read the error message. It tells you, that you should move the `_apps` variable above your functions to your other variables.

Comment: ... or to make it private

Comment: I am not getting that error after moving it above to the top. I am still getting the trailing whitespace errors however.